# Parsing generic XHR response into JSON objects

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Say that we use XMLHttpRequest to perform a `GET` request on an API endpoint. The endpoint returns some kind of JSON response (it can be one JSON object or an array of JSON objects). What is the best way to take these response and convert it into a generic JSON object to save in memory?

For example, here is some code

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('get', myURL);
arr = []
xhr.onload = function ()
{
    if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
        response = xhr.response
        // save every incoming JSON object into arr
    }
}
```

I want to be able to write something generic (ie. it will work on any API endpoint that returns a JSON). Does anyone have any recommendations or a library to go about this?

Comment: If your response is a stringified JSON object then you can use JSON.parse method to convert it back to JSON object.

Comment: I assume `xhr.responseText` would qualify as a stringified JSON? What would you do if you get a stringified array of JSON?

Comment: If the stringified text is a JSON array then JSON.parse will convert it to json array. Just try it.